# Spark Context is not automatically created in Scala Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark

I read in a Spark book :

Driver programs access Spark through a SparkContext object, which represents a
connection to a computing cluster. In the shell, a SparkContext is automatically created for you as the variable called sc. Try printing out sc to see its type

> > > sc

When I enter sc, it gives me an error 20 value sc not found. Any idea why is sc  not automatically created in my scala spark shell?

I try to manually create a sc and it gave me an error saying there is already a spark context in the JVM. Please see pic :

http://s30.photobucket.com/user/kctestingeas1/media/No%20Spark%20Context.jpg.html

I believe i am already in scala spark shell as you can see on the top of my cmd window indicating bin\spark-shell

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Hopefully you found the answer to your question, because I am encountering the same issue as well.

In the meantime, use this workaround. In the scala spark shell, enter:

1. import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
2. val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

You then have access to sc.